# Powershell robocopy multiple wildcards

Tags: powershell, conditional-statements, wildcard, robocopy

For wildcard flags can I say only copy files with both `sp` and `MPK` in the name?

```
$source = "D:\scripts\watcher\2015-007"
$destination = "K:\public\scripts\watcher\2015-006"
$sourceOptions = "*sp* *MPK* /COPYALL"
$sourceOptions2 = "*sp* /COPYALL"
$copyOptions = "/Z /SECFIX /XX /MT[:32] /LOG+:$destination\logs\RoboLog.txt /V /R:5 /W:1" 


New-Item K:\public\scripts\watcher\2015-006\logs -ErrorAction SilentlyContinue -type directory

Start-Process robocopy -ArgumentList "$source $destination $sourceOptions $copyOptions" -wait -NoNewWindow -PassThru
```

I am running robocopy with PowerShell, I created some variables and put them in the right sequence so that they work with robocopy.

In variable `$sourceOptions` I define some wild cards for robocopy.
Anything with `sp` or `MPK` in the file name get moved over to the destination.

For wildcard flags can I say only copy files with both `sp` and `MPK` in the name?

Comment: Don't try too hard. [This article](http://windowsitpro.com/powershell/running-executables-powershell) provides some help on how to correctly pass command-line arguments to programs in PowerShell.

Answer (score 4):

I had this same question then decided to try multiple `/IF` (**I**nclude **F**ile) flags and it worked.
eg: `robocopy . otherdir\ /IF *sp* /IF *MPK*`

will copy both files containing `sp` and files containing `MPK` from the current dir to `otherdir\`

hope that helps.

Answer (score 0):

Use combination of `*sp*MPK*` and `*MPK*sp*` should archive your goal of copying files with both `sp` and `MPK` in the name.